# Using jQuery to do an onClick div refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

This should work right? I have not a clue as to why it's not. I have to be doing something wrong.

```
<div id="randomdiv">text</div>
    <a id="refresh">click</a>

    <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#refresh").click(function() {
         $("#randomdiv").load("index.php")
      })
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Can I use this function say, from a child page to a parent page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Onclick refresh only div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959641/onclick-refresh-only-div)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What happen if you do this?

```
<a id="refresh" href="#">click</a>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
         $("#randomdiv").load("index.php")
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: When I do that, it works HAHA. Forgot to put the href, wow. Thanks!

Comment: What if the div I'd like to refresh is a Google map for instance. How do you go about doing that?