# Onclick refresh only div

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi i need help with refreshing div, but not auto refresh!

I have my div like this.

```
<div id="osvezi">
<?php include('moduli/skupina_artiklov/osvezi.php'); ?>
</div>
```

I want that i clicked some button they refreshed me only div osvezi.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Onclick reload the div only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413200/onclick-reload-the-div-only)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) with a selector like this:

```
$(function() {       //run when the document's ready, elements are loaded
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#osvezi").load(location.href + " #osvezi > *");
  });
});
```

This responds to an element with `id="mybutton"` being clicked and refetches the page but only that portion.  Alternatively, if `moduli/skupina_artiklov/osvezi.php` is accessible directly, you can just load that directly (more efficient!) this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#osvezi").load("moduli/skupina_artiklov/osvezi.php");
  });
});
```

Comment: $(function() {       //run when the document's ready, elements are loaded
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#osvezi").load(location.href + " #osvezi > *");
  });
});

This refresh me div but i used in my php file sestavljen_artikel.php
a jquery function to feel me another select

Comment: @Alen - I don't follow your question, can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I have in sestavljen_artikel.php this div osvezi. And in this file i have jquery code that feel me another select.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nalozi() {
        var id_skupine = $('#skupina option:selected').val();
        $('#artikel option').remove();

        //$('#artikel').append('<option value="'+id_skupine+'">'+id_skupine+'</option>');
        $.getJSON('moduli/skupina_artiklov/artikli.php', {id_skupine:$('#skupina').val()}, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index,item) {
                $("#artikel").append("<option value=" + item.id + "-" + item.cena + ">" + item.ime_artikla + " - " + item.storitev + " (" + item.cena + " €" + ")" + "</option>"); 
            });
        });
    } 
</script>
```

But when they refreshed me div, this function not working and other function.